# get all parents of a path with linq

Tags: c#, linq, path, filepath

I'd like to get all parents of a path without an explicit loop so that I can eliminate this method entirely.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetParentPaths(string path)
{
    while (Path.GetDirectoryName(path) != Path.GetPathRoot(path))
    {
        path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        yield return path;
    }
}
```

How could this be done cleanly with LINQ?

given

```
c:\a\b\c
```

should return the following (order doesn't matter)

```
c:\a
c:\a\b
```

**update:**

@Tomas Petricek's answer led me to [Jon Skeet's Generator implementation](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/159e4793-6b17-4e89-bd94-3bde8a5f2d50/iterators-iterator-block.aspx) and I ended up with the following:

```
path.Generate(Path.GetDirectoryName)
    .Skip(1) // the original
    .TakeWhile(p => p != Path.GetPathRoot(p))
```

using

```
public static class TExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(this T initial, Func<T, T> next) 
    {
        var current = initial;
        while (true)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = next(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard methods provided by `Enumerable` aren't powerful enough to encode `while` loop easily. If you want to rewrite the code by calling some general purpose method, you'll need to implement some general purpose method too. Your problem could be nicely solved if you added a `Generate` method:

```
EnumerableEx.Generate(path, path => 
  Path.GetDirectoryName(path) != Path.GetPathRoot(path) 
  ? Path.GetDirectoryName(path) : null);
```

The idea of the `Generate` method is that it keeps calling the provided lambda function repeatedly to generate new state (in this case `path`) until it returns `null`. The method yields all generated values as it goes. You can write `Generate` like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(T initial, Func<T, T> next) {
  T current = initial;
  while(true) {
    current = next(current);
    if (current == default(T)) return;
    yield return current;
  }
}
```

The method essentially just hides a reusable pattern that was used in your original method. The specific behavior is passed as a function, so you could use the method for many different purposes.

Comment: 'current == default(T)' doesn't seem to compile unless the Generate method is marked with 'where T : class' - also 'return' on that line should be 'yield break'

Comment: @Handcraftsman: Thanks for the correction. Stackoverflow doesn't have built-in C# compiler :-) unfortunatelly.